# how to avoid manually copying csproj files in docker file

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core-webapi

I have multiple dotnet projects with multi level nesting and I am specifying each `csproj` with their path structure below for each and every application's docker file.

Whenever there is a addition and deletion of projects all docker file have to be update.

Can I avoid it and make some generic docker file?

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY My.sln .

COPY ["Core/Events.csproj", "Core/"]
COPY ["Core/Infra/Services/Services.csproj", "Core/Infra/Services/"]
COPY ["Features/Feature.A.API/Feature.A.API.csproj", "Features/Feature.A.API/"]

RUN dotnet restore

COPY . .
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store all needed projects in a root dir lets call it `src` then you just have to use the main project for restore/build/publish (the one with your asp .net core webapi), all the other sources (dependencies) needed during build would then be present (in the src dir), with correct paths.

For example:

- src/Core/....
- src/Features/...
- src/Features/Feature.A.API/Dockerfile

The docker file would then look like this (aspnet 5.0):

with place holders:

- [API_DIR] in your case: `Features/Feature.A.API/`
- [API_PROJECT] in your case: `Feature.A.API`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/[API_DIR]/[API_PROJECT].csproj", "[API_DIR]/"]
RUN dotnet restore "[API_DIR]/[API_PROJECT].csproj"
COPY ["src/", "."]
WORKDIR "src/[API_DIR]"
RUN dotnet build "[API_PROJECT].csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "[API_PROJECT].csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "[API_PROJECT].dll"]
```

Run it from Folder which contains the `src` dir (this is your build context), with:

```
docker build src/Features/Feature.A.API/Dockerfile
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @kraego. My concern here is if tomorrow I added a new feature  `Features/Feature.B.API/`, then again we have to add those manually in each feature's docker file, how to avoid it? Plus how to copy project reference for class library within `Core` folder or inside some subfolder?

Comment: Hi, it would help me to understand: What is a feature for you? A new Endpoint? A new Microservice? ... How are these features working together?